# How to Automount a CIFS share after WiFi connects on Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've got Raspbian running on RaspberryPi 2. I've a WIFI dongle, configured network/interfaces to automatically connect to my home network... all works great.

I've a windows share on my LAN that I want to mount on raspbian. I edited `/etc/fstab` file. My added line works fine when I use Ethernet cable, it automatically mounts the share on boot. However, when on WiFi it doesn't. I'm guessing it runs fstab too early before the WiFi connects.... also if I run `sudo mount -a`, it reads the rule from fstab and applies it just fine...

My question is, how can I get the system to automount AFTER there is an available connection? or after it acquires an IP maybe?

I looked at udev rules but I'm not sure if that's the way to go...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look into "network interface configuration for ifup and ifdown" with

```
man interfaces
```

The configuration file allows several "command" options. In your case you might want to take a look into the option

```
post-up command
```

which is run after the interface is brought up.

Answer (score 0):

While the NFS-specific mount binary supports a `bg` option, the CIFS mount does not.

Options I can think of:

- Create a script that attempts to perform the mount, but sleeps and loops if unsuccessful.  Exit if mount successful.  Run as a startup script.
- Install and use the automounter, `autofs`.